# Change session id

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

We want to renew the id of a session manually after a user has logged in.

There are different solutions on the web for this problem but none has worked for us, e. g.:

```
SessionIDManager manager = new SessionIDManager();
string newId = Manager.CreateSessionID(Context);
string oldId = Context.Session.SessionID;
bool redirected = false;
bool isAdded = false;
manager.SaveSessionID(Context, newId,out redirected, out isAdded);
```

When executing this code, the new session id is equal to the old id (but the variable newId keeps the correct new value) so it looks like the newId variable isn't assigned.

Comment: This is possible but you are going to lose all values stored in the old session. Is this acceptable for you? If it is I can show you how to change the session id after authenticating.

Comment: *When* are you checking that new session ID? Usually the old ID only gets renewed on a new request. Also, why this way and not Session.Abandon?

Comment: It is acceptable to me to lose all values stored in the session because I start adding data to the session AFTER login.
Session.Abandon doesn't work for me because after calling Session.Abandon the rest of the method is not executed. :-(.